# How to create an API that returns data from multiple tables in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two entity classes called `AccountEntity` and `ProjectEntitiesEntity`. The `AccountEntity` consists of three entities as:

```
public class AccountEntity : BaseEntity
{
  public long AccountNumber { get; set; }
  public AccountTypeEnum AccountType { get; set; }
  public bool Privacy { get; set; }
}
```

The `ProjectEntitiesEntity` class consists of following entities:

```
public class ProjectEntitiesEntity : BaseEntity
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ProjectEntitiesEnum Type { get; set; } 
        public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

So, I want an api that would return data from both the table combined in the paginated form. Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
public async Task <PaginatedList<AccountVM>> GetProjectEntitiesList(DataParameters parameters)
{
            var pageIndex = parameters?.PageNumber ?? 1;
            var pageSize = parameters?.PageSize ?? 1;

            var accQueryList = _context.ProjectEntities.Include(k => k.ContactAddress).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Where(x => true);

            var acc = _context.Accounts.Include(x => x.AccountManagerAddress).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Where(x => x.AccountType==AccountTypeEnum.ProjectProponent);

            //dynamic obj3 = accQueryList.Union(acc);

            var result = accQueryList.AsEnumerable().Concat<object>(acc.AsEnumerable()).ToList();

            //var tp = acc.GetType();
            //Console.WriteLine(result);
            var count = await accQueryList.CountAsync();

            //List with paging
            //var items = _mapper.Map<List<ProjectEntitiesDto>>(await accQueryList.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync());

            //Check if Account KYC is added and submitted
            var returnView = new PaginatedResponseVM<ProjectEntitiesDto>(count, items);

            return returnView;
}
```

Yes, I am using `ProjectEntitesDto` file in the mapper and the problem is it will only return data from `ProjectEntities` table and not from `Account` Table. If I use `AccountDto` then it will only return data from `Account` table only. I think I have to merge the Dto files as well but have no idea how to achieve it.

To put it in a simple form, I am trying to display records from two tables in a tabular form at the front with single pagination.

So, could someone possibly shed some light on this? Any help would be more than appreciable.

Comment: I don't see how these two tables can be linked. Which columns do you expect to be albe to join on? Given an Account Number, which projects should appear? Given a project, which accounts should appear?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for replying. I think you are trying to point out foreign key or common columns to make a join relations. There are no common columns as of now. However, I am trying to show results such as all the rows available from ProjectEntities table and all the accounts who has '0' value for AccountTypeEnum AccountType would be returned in the response. Actually, those two tables are there to store two different types of accounts.

Comment: _return data from both the table combined in the paginated form_ You need to define how to do "both the table combined" are you saying you want two display two seperate unrelated tables on one page, represented in two different paginated grids?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you for the follow-up. I want the data from both the tables combined in the same response and same pagination. If those two tables can not be combined as the way I am trying to then your suggestions are welcomed. The problem is the ProjectEntities table is not an expanded table from the Accounts table. Those two tables have separate types of accounts stored and I am trying to display them on the same page at the front end in a combined form with single pagination to control that combination.

Comment: What if account has one row and project has 1000. What do you expect when you go to the next page? Should account still show up? Pretty sure this kind of logic is not built into the PaginatedList class. Since this is purely a front end thing, I suggest you do a seperate paginated API per entity, then on the front end use two grids + AJAX to paginate them individually.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, two tables can have varied numbers of records. If one table finishes on the first page then the second page should show records from the second table only. To put it in a simple form, I am trying to display records from two tables in a tabular form at the front with single pagination. Having two paginations at the front will only confuse users, isn't it?

Comment: I have never seen what you are describing in a user interface ever. You can do what you want but you'll probably have to write your own class for it because it is that out of the ordinary. If you can, I suggest you do some research on UX, or try and find examples on how two completey unrelated tables should be shown in a user interface. It doesn't make any sense to me that you would show two unrelated tables and yet have some kind of synchronised pagination going on. When I have done this in the past, I put two different tables on two different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can combine the DTOs or the option I prefer is to inherit the DTO.
The next step is to map properly from the Entity/Data-Model.
You need to install package: AutoMapper
Make sure properties in DTO & Entity have same name to map automatically.
Each property you want as result in your API should me mapped properly.

```
public class AccountDTO : ProjectDTO
{
  public long AccountNumber { get; set; }
  public AccountTypeEnum AccountType { get; set; }
  public bool Privacy { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectDTO
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ProjectEntitiesEnum Type { get; set; } 
  public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can map it like this:

```
CreateMap<AccountEntity , AccountDTO>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Name , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectEntitiesEntity .Name))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Type , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectEntitiesEntity .Type ))
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Status , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectEntitiesEntity .Status ))
```